# PostFix - Dovecot - Nottfy on Email To / From someone

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot

So for reasons unknown, I need to block emails To or From a certain email address.

I don't care what is in the emails, but I would like a notification email sent to another address if possible, however this is not vital.

Details:
Kernel 2.8.18
Dovecot - 1.0.rc15
Postfix - 2.3.3

Thanks.

---

Details:

Ok so I've added

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
```

to /etc/postfix/main.cf

added

```
myemail@address.com DISCARD TestDiscard
```

to /etc/postfix/access

ran

```
postmap /etc/postfix/access
```

Reloaded / Restarted postfix, and emails still get sent to and from the email address blocked.

Does this setting in /etc/postfix/main.cf make a difference:

```
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Dovecot has nothing to do with this, it should all be done in the MTA.

Blocking based on the sender or recipient is trivial -- just use access lists (as per `access`(5)) in the sender and recipient restriction configs.  Notifying another e-mail address is, IMO, best handled by a log parser.

Comment: Ok, got that, /etc/postfix/access done, added it to the config file. But no blocking, accepting all emails, sending all emails. I'll post details

Answer (score 1):

Try using [smtpd_recipient_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) instead of smtpd_client_restrictions. The client option puts restrictions on the client that is connecting to the server, while the recipient option puts a restriction on the recipient email address, in this case you want the recipient and not the client restrictions.

The method you put will restrict any mail coming from the address myemail@address.com, not to that address.